# Update Multiplas Colunas

Tags: query, sql-update, multiple

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso fazer um update na tabela SB1300 nos campos B1_DESC e B1_CODBAR para diversas linhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O where será o B1_XCODORI

Consigo fazer numa mesma query?

Answer (score 1):

Sim você consegue, sua instrução update ficaria da seguinte maneira

```
update SB1300 
set B1_DESC = 'novo valor', B1_CODBAR = 'novo valor'
where B1_XCODORI = /*sua condição*/
```